# XSLT / XML - how to sum 2 numbers using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently our product feed in  .xml file generate all prices in euro:

```
  <price>37.990000</price>
  <recommended_price>111.50</recommended_price>
  <rate_currency_change>4.37</rate_currency_change>
```

Now I need convert this before export (convers via xslt).

I need convert price * rate

So

- 37.990000 * 4.37 = 166.01
- 111.50 * 4.37 = 487.25

and after convert finally should be xml after convert currency to PLN:

```
  <price>166.01</price>
  <recommended_price>487.25</recommended_price>
  <rate_currency_change>4.37</rate_currency_change>
```

Can anyone help write xslt template?

update:
original xml feed:

```
<Items>
 <item>
  <price>37.990000</price>
  <recommended_price>111.50</recommended_price>
  <rate_currency_change>4.37</rate_currency_change>
  </item>
</Items>
```

I use xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Items/item">
    <item>
      <price><xsl:value-of select="./price * ./rate_currency_change"/></price>
      <recommended_price><xsl:value-of select="./recommended_price * ./rate_currency_change"/></recommended_price>
      <rate><xsl:value-of select="./rate_currency_change"/></rate>
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but we get result:

```
<item>
<price>166.01</price>
<recommended_price>487.25</recommended_price>
<rate_currency_change>4.32</rate_currency_change>
</item>
```

missing elements:

```
<Items></Items>
```

Comment: You've to add the element: <xsl:template match="/"><Items><xsl:for-each select="Items/item">....</xsl:for-each><Items>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for XSLT2 try

Input:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <price>37.990000</price>
    <recommended_price>111.50</recommended_price>
    <rate>4.37</rate>
  </product>
</products>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <products>
  <xsl:for-each select="products/product">
    <product>
      <price><xsl:value-of select="./price * ./rate"/></price>
      <recommended_price><xsl:value-of select="./recommended_price * ./rate"/></recommended_price>
      <rate><xsl:value-of select="./rate"/></rate>
    </product>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </products>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution works, but why use a for-loop and why rebuild all the structure when all that needs to be changed are two elements?

Comment: @Sebastien according to question it's a feed, so perhaps more than one item... And for xslt beginners a simple plain copy is more readable I think

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this. If you need to cut-off/round the numbers your can use the [`format-number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-number) function: `format-number(.*../rate, '#.##')`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="price | recommended_price">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select=".*../rate_currency_change"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDt/2